# Customer satisfaction survey and checkbox to not ask him/her again

Tags: jquery, sweetalert2

I am implementing a customer satisfaction module with use Sweet Alert 2.

Almost everything is working, the only pending activity is to control when the client decide to not see the satisfaction survey screen again.

The idea is to use a checkbox with the message "Do not ask me again." and the confirm button or the same checkbox and dismiss button.

In the same customer action, I will show the messages and update a database column table as a flag 1 or 0.

The code developed until now is the following:

```
swal({
    title: 'Survey',
    html: 'Would you like to answer a customer survey?',
    type: 'question',
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonText: 'No',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
    cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
    buttonsStyling: true,
    input: 'checkbox',
    inputPlaceholder: 'Do not ask me again'

}).then(function(inputValue) {

    win = window.open(win, '_blank');

    if (win) {

        //Browser has allowed it to be opened
        win.focus();

        swal({
            html: 'The company thanks you for your participation',
            type: 'success'
        });

        // if the customer checked to not see the survey requisition again call a function that update the database (1 for ask again and 0 to not)
        if (inputValue) {
            customerSurvey(customerId, 0);
        }

    } else {

        swal({
            title: 'Atention!',
            html: 'Please, allow your browser to display popups window.',
            type: 'warning'
        });

    }

}, function (dismiss) {

    swal({
        //title: 'Information!',
        html: 'Thank you for your attention.',
        type: 'info'
    });

});
```

As you can see, it works as I desire just when the customer click on checkbox and the button "Yes", when the first function has the inputValue as parameter. But, how do we deal with the second function on dismiss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global variables and listen for when the checkbox changes and assign the global variable. Which can be then used in your dismissed function.

```
var checkboxVal = false;
swal({
    title: 'Survey',
    html: 'Would you like to answer a customer survey?',
    type: 'question',
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonText: 'No',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
    cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
    buttonsStyling: true,
    input: 'checkbox',
    inputPlaceholder: 'Do not ask me again'
}).then(function (inputValue) {

    win = window.open(win, '_blank');

    if (win) {

        //Browser has allowed it to be opened
        win.focus();

        swal({
            html: 'The company thanks you for your participation',
            type: 'success'
        });

        // if the customer checked to not see the survey requisition again call a function that update the database (1 for ask again and 0 to not)
        if (inputValue) {
            customerSurvey(customerId, 0);
        }
    } else {
        swal({
            title: 'Atention!',
            html: 'Please, allow your browser to display popups window.',
            type: 'warning'
        });
    }
}, function (dismiss) {
    if (checkboxVal) {
        console.log("user has checked they do not want to view this popup again.");
        //handle your database call here
    }

    swal({
        //title: 'Information!',
        html: 'Thank you for your attention.',
        type: 'info'
    });
});

  /*
   *The following code handles when the checkbox has changed
   */
$('#swal2-checkbox').change(
    function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            checkboxVal = true;
        } else {
            checkboxVal = true;
        }
    });
```

Here is a working [jSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thedos/m9as6863/10/).

I hope this helps, Good luck!

Comment: The second suggestion worked as desired, but, I do not know why, it shows a traditional window alert without text on it and a "ok" button on front of the sweet alert window. I have tested on Firefox and Google chrome. The first suggestion did not worked.

Comment: Good to hear the second suggestion worked for you. However, I'm not sure I understand what your issue is now? Are you seeing a normal browser alert? I will add a jsFiddle of the working code for you if that helps.

Comment: I have edited my answer adding a jSfiddle and removed the first suggestion as it wasn't working for you.

Comment: Thank you @Hayden Passmore I will check it out at work on tomorrow morning. The source code is in the company server. Maybe something is printing out as a response from the function/method that updates the database.

Comment: Thank you again @Hayden Passmore, now everything is working fine. I appreciate your help.